# Is it possible to keep variable values after page reloaded in JavaScript without using cookie and local storage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I am trying to keep values for a page over user interaction. I know I can do it using `cookie and local storage`. But I am curious to know that is there any way to do it without using `cookie and local storage`. If it is possible then how?

```
Actually I am asking to do it without any storage.
```

Comment: I think It is impossible without any storage.

Answer (score 1):

Update url for each action made by user so you can retain the parameters you want on page reload, I don't think we have any other way

Answer (score 0):

[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) is another option for client-side storage. Its API is a bit complex though, so to use it, you might want a library like [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) instead.

Another option is to save the values by saving them in a database on the server, though for reliable retrieval without storing any information client-side, the user will have to be able to input something unique to them (such as username/password - the server checking their IP addresses likely won't be enough, since IP addresses are often shared)

Comment: Actually I am asking to do it without any storage. BTW thanks.

Comment: Your question said *without using cookie and local storage*, so I posted methods which do not use cookies nor local storage